# face recognition on raspberry pi create LBP

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I just finished a work program to faces recognition using python on ubuntu system

But when you want to move the work to "Raspberry pi" gives this error

this is full error :
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

What is the solution

Thank you

```
import cv2
import sys
import cv
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
labeltest=[]
Images=[]
Len=0

model = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1,8,8,8,70.0)

Labels=[]
textsay=""

# *********** Read *****************\\
def read():
    arr={}
    with open("csv.ext") as f:
        for line in f:
            arr=line.split("%",2)

            labeltest.append(arr[1])
            Images.append(cv2.imread(arr[0],cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    label=range(0,len(labeltest))
    for i in range(0,len(labeltest)):
        label[i]=int(labeltest[i])

    print (label)
    model.train(np.asarray(Images),np.asarray(label))


    model.save("mezo.xml")


    model.load("mezo.xml")




# //*********** Read *****************


def writetofile(key):
    fo = open("csv.ext", "a+")
    fo.write(key)
    fo.write("\n")


def searchName(key):
    lines=tuple(open("Names.txt","r"))
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        test=lines[i].split("\n")
        print test[0]
        if str(key.lower())==str(test[0].lower()):
            return i
    return -1

def readName():
    lines=tuple(open("Names.txt","r"))
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        Labels.append(lines[i])
    print Labels

def AddName(key):
    fo = open("Names.txt", "a+")
    fo.write(key)
    fo.write("\n")
    readName()


# *********** Add *****************\\

def Add(faces,gray):
    count=Len+100
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        filename = "/home/mohammad/Desktop/traning/%03d"%count +".pgm"
        f=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        f=cv2.resize(f,(92,112),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
        newName=raw_input("Enter the Name : ")
        index=searchName(newName)
        if index==-1:
                index=len(Labels)
                AddName(newName)
        filenameIn = filename+"%"+str(index)
        writetofile(filenameIn)
        cv2.imwrite(filename,f)
        count+=1
    read()

# //*********** Add *****************

path={}
path=glob.glob("/home/mohammad/Desktop/traning/*.pgm")
Len=len(path)-1
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
count=0
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
read();
readName()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        cv2.waitKey(10)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        frame,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
        # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                f=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                f=cv2.resize(f,(92,112),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
                cv2.imwrite("11.pgm",f)
                label, confidence = model.predict(f)
                print"Threshold : ", model.getDouble("threshold")
                if label>-1:
                        if Labels[label] != textsay:
                            cmd = 'espeak "{0}" 2>/dev/null'.format(Labels[label])
                            os.system(cmd)
                        textsay=Labels[label]  
                        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                        cv2.putText(frame,Labels[label],(x,y-10), font, 1.0,(255,255,255))
                        print "\n"+str(Labels[label])+"   |    "+str(confidence)



  # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        k=cv2.waitKey(5)& 0xFF
        if  k==97 :
                Add(faces,gray)
        if k==27:
                exit()
```

Comment: You're not providing enough to trace the error. You should attach the code where this call is being made (and/or debug that part).

Comment: i am sorry
i  added code

Comment: Please also add the *full* trace of the error.

Comment: this is full error :
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Comment: no no i wrote this code on ubuntu and running it but on raspberry do not work

Comment: And your pi has (the same) opencv as well?

Comment: yes the same 
i try to find " cv2.createLBPHFaceReconizer " on raspberry pi
in ubuntu i find it but in pi no

Comment: your opencv install on pi/ubuntu seems to differ. can you shed some light on that ?

Comment: i use 
sudo apt-get install python-opencv 
in two os

Comment: Yeah but that doesnt have to be from the SAME repository: Download and compile opencv manually on both if cv2.__version__ differs.

Comment: yeah rigth on ubuntu the version is " '2.4.8' "  but on Raspberry is " 2.4.1"

now can you help me how can download and install manually ?

Comment: Download from http://opencv.org/. Make sure you have gcc and cmake on your system. Then you have to make and make install, just follow the documentation for openCV. It will take some compile time to do it on the Pi, but without good knowledge of cross compilation it is the most reliable way to do it. If you are confident in your cross compilation you could as well compile on a more powerful computer.